# Dúvidas com constantes no React

Tags: react, componentes

Olá,

Esse é meu primeiro projeto com React Js e estou com uma dúvida, imagino eu, básica.

Tenho código abaixo que está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon  } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import './Header.scss';

import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';

import { faUserCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

export default class Header extends Component { 
  render() {

    function handleBurgerBtn() {
      const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
      const navigationWindow = document.getElementById("navigationWindow");
      const loginWindow = document.getElementById("loginWindow");

      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

      navigationWindow.style.display = 'block';
      loginWindow.style.display = 'none';
      mobile.classList.toggle("eventNavigationWindow");
    }
    function handleLoginBtn() {
      const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
      const navigationWindow = document.getElementById("navigationWindow");
      const loginWindow = document.getElementById("loginWindow");

      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

      navigationWindow.style.display = 'none';
      loginWindow.style.display = 'block';
      mobile.classList.toggle("eventLoginWindow");
    };
    return (
        <header>
          <nav>
            <div id="burgerBtn" onClick={ () => handleBurgerBtn() }></div>
            <div id="loginBtn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faUserCircle } onClick={ ()=> handleLoginBtn() } /></div>
          </nav>
          <div id="top">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src={ logo } alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="localisation">
              <p class="text">Você está em</p>
              <p class="city">Botucatu <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="searchBar">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <form>
                  <input 
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="O que: ex: pizzaria, drogaria, loja, etc."
                    class="form-control searchField"
                  />      
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
    );
  }
}
```

A dúvida é a seguinte: tenho duas funções e ambas tem o mesmo trecho de código:

```
const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
const navigationWindow = document.getElementById("navigationWindow");
const loginWindow = document.getElementById("loginWindow");
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de eu utilizar, declarar estas constantes antes das funções de reutilizar nas duas funções.

Pensei em usar state mais não consegui implementar. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, para você chegar neste resultado, você precisaria do seguinte:

1 - As funções podem ser retiradas do método "render" e inseridas acima dele (dentro da classe Header)
2 - Estas constantes você pode criar fora da classe.

O seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon  } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import './Header.scss';

import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';

import { faUserCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
const navigationWindow = document.getElementById("navigationWindow");
const loginWindow = document.getElementById("loginWindow");

export default class Header extends Component { 
 handleBurgerBtn = () => {
     

      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

      navigationWindow.style.display = 'block';
      loginWindow.style.display = 'none';
      mobile.classList.toggle("eventNavigationWindow");
    }
    handleLoginBtn = () =>  {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

      navigationWindow.style.display = 'none';
      loginWindow.style.display = 'block';
  mobile.classList.toggle("eventLoginWindow");
    };

  render() {

    
    return (
        <header>
          <nav>
            <div id="burgerBtn" onClick={ () => this.handleBurgerBtn }></div>
            <div id="loginBtn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faUserCircle } onClick={ ()=> this.handleLoginBtn } /></div>
          </nav>
          <div id="top">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src={ logo } alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="localisation">
              <p class="text">Você está em</p>
              <p class="city">Botucatu <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="searchBar">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <form>
                  <input 
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="O que: ex: pizzaria, drogaria, loja, etc."
                    class="form-control searchField"
                  />      
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Rapaz, não funcionou dá erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. Verifiquei via console.log o retorno da constante navigationWindow dentro da função no momento do clique, retornar null

Comment: No seu código de exemplo eu não tenho elementos com o "id" mobile, navigationWindow e loginWindow. Os elementos que eu identifiquei com id são  loginBtn, top, localisation e searchBar

Answer (score -1):

Consegui usando state, segue o código:

```js
//Importando modulos
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon  } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

//CSS
import './Header.scss';

//Imagens
import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';

// Icones
import { faUserCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

export default class Header extends Component { 
  state= {
    burgerBtn: '',    
    loginBtn: '',
    loginWindow: '',
    mobile: '',
    navigationWindow: '',
    searchWindow: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      burgerBtn: document.getElementById("burgerBtn"),    
      loginBtn: document.getElementById("loginBtn"),
      loginWindow: document.getElementById("loginWindow"),
      mobile: document.getElementById("mobile"),
      navigationWindow: document.getElementById("navigationWindow"),
      searchWindow: document.getElementById("searchWindow")
    })
  }

  handleBurgerBtn = () => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

    this.state.navigationWindow.style.display = 'block';
    this.state.loginWindow.style.display = 'none';
    this.state.mobile.classList.toggle("eventNavigationWindow");
  }

  handleLoginBtn = () => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

    this.state.navigationWindow.style.display = 'none';
    this.state.loginWindow.style.display = 'block';
    this.state.mobile.classList.toggle("eventLoginWindow");
  }

  handleSearchField = () => {
    this.state.navigationWindow.style.display = 'none';
    this.state.searchWindow.style.display = 'block';
    this.state.burgerBtn.style.display = 'none';
    this.state.loginBtn.style.display = 'none';
    this.state.mobile.classList.toggle("eventSearchWindow");
  }

  render() {


    return (
        <header>
          <nav>
            <div id="burgerBtn" onClick={ () => this.handleBurgerBtn() }></div>
            <div id="loginBtn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faUserCircle } onClick={ ()=> this.handleLoginBtn() } /></div>
          </nav>
          <div id="top">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src={ logo } alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="localisation">
              <p className="text">Você está em</p>
              <p className="city">Botucatu <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="searchBar">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12">
                <form>
                  <input 
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="O que: ex: pizzaria, drogaria, loja, etc."
                    className="form-control searchField"
                    onClick={ () => this.handleSearchField() }
                  />      
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Obrigado pelas dicas! ;)